# Google Data Studio Date

Tags: looker-studio

I'm currently working with CSV data and trying to import into datastudio.
The Date format in CSV is "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" EXAMPLE: "12/05/2021 16:30"

When I put data into the data studio
The date came out as "5 DEC 2021" (A date in the future?)

Please, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

It is parsing your date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format (month before the day), which is very common problem.

To avoid this kind of problem, I would say it is a good practice to always use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, that means `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If you can't change the CSV data source, I suggest you to treat the column as a `STRING` and add a calculated field to parse the string creating a new date field.  Like in this example:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%d/%m/%E4Y %H:%M", Your_CSV_Field)  # if the time part is relevant
PARSE_DATE("%d/%m/%E4Y", Your_CSV_Field)            # if the time part is NOT relevant
```

This way, you can freely use any date format.